# Building Eclipse RCP application to run in GUI and in headless mode

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to build an Eclipse RCP application such that it can be run in GUI mode and in headless (console) mode. Basically, something like this:

In GUI mode:

```
  eclipse.exe -application appName <more args>
```

In console (headless) mode:

```
  eclipse.exe  -console -application appName  <more args>    OR
  eclipsec.exe -application appName  <more args>
```

I would like to do the build such that both "eclipse.exe" and "eclipsec.exe" are generated using a single step/process.

BTW, I am using (or have to use) Eclipse 3.6.x.

Comment: What's your question? That's all supported by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the `IApplication.start(IApplicationContext)` method calls `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(...)` will you have an Eclipse application with a UI.

The usual way to support this is via different applications - see the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point - but you can also have a single `IApplication` that is controlled via a application command argument (see `IApplicationContext.getArguments()`).

If your application is based on the Eclipse IDE, then of cause this later option is not possible and you have to use separate application IDs. Please note that the Eclipse IDE already comes with ~15 applications built-in - apart from the IDE itself, this is primary various p2 applications.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I was doing all this, but it was still not working. No messages were displayed on the console without Eclipse IDE. However, those messages were displayed using "System.out.println()" within IDE. (Console is null within IDE.) 

Anyway, I checked again. The problem was the way RCP application was started. The application was started from inside a batch file. And, they way that batch file was run, its stdout was blocked. That is why the application was unable to display anything on console.

Changing the way how the application started, fixed the problem.
Thanks again.